# SQLite unable to open database file: Laravel + Windows

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I'm try use a sqlite database in my laravel project, in local environment for dev (Windows 8.1 with AMMPS), but when I try run a `migrate:instal` command, this error apeear:

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file

**My database config file (app/config/local/database.php):**

```
<?php

return array(
    'default' => 'sqlite',

    'connections' => array(
        'sqlite' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => __DIR__ . '\..\..\database\production.sqlite',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: maybe the database is locked?

Comment: how, if not I'm wearing anywhere?

Comment: The final slash in your database path should be a backslash \ instead of a forward slash /.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is not that.

Comment: Have you tried using an sqlite ide such as [SQLite Expert Personal is freeware](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/download.html). That way you will know the db is usable.

Comment: Do you have the file `production.sqlite`? Does your "web user" have permissions to read that file? Also, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668156/how-to-prevent-sqlite-sqlstatehy000-14

Answer (score 19):

try to remove the DB_DATABASE="yourdatabase" variable in your .env file

Comment: @JakubKopyś Because the `.env` file's values are loaded from `config/database.php` as long as the keys are listed inside, no matter what their value is. If a key is not found in the `.env` file, it defaults to the value set in `config/database.php`, which would be `.../database/database.sqlite` in the case of `DB_DATABASE` (as of Laravel 5.3)

Answer (score 4):

If the permissions allow to write on the folder just create the storage folders.

e-g, this how I fix the problem.

in `config/database.php` :

```
'connections' => [

  'sqlite' => [
      'driver'   => 'sqlite',
      'database' => storage_path('database/databaseName.sqlite'),
      'prefix'   => '',
  ],
```

Then if you run on your terminal `php artisan migrate`, it returns you the `[PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file`

Create the path folder by your own, e-g in your terminal `mkdir storage/database/databaseName.sqlite`

Make sure the permissions allow you to write, then re-run the command `php artisan migrate`, it returns you the success message : `Migration table created successfully`.

Answer (score 2):

On laravel 5.3.x

This was the only thing that worked for me:

> Change DB_CONNECTION from "mysql" to "sqlite". Because this is an
>   sqlite database, you can delete all the other DB_* items in that .env
>   file.
>
> APP_ENV=local APP_KEY=base64: APP_DEBUG=true APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
>   APP_URL=http://localhost
>
> DB_CONNECTION=sqlite

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make sqlite file available at the defined path.  In larvel 5.7, I just used following command and run migration.

```
touch /absolute/path/of/db.sqlite
```

That will create an empty file at defined location and you are good to go.

Observation: In Larvel 5.7, .sqlite file should be already available at defined location.

For windows, right click and create new file with the defined name at defined location.

Answer (score 1):

try change the file `databaseName.sqlite` permission database to writeable and readable. Maybe change permissions folder `database` also.

In the production server change this file database to private directory for security.

Answer (score 1):

Well it may be late but I have also faced the problem in `ubuntu` environment, here exactly how I overcome this issue.

You have to pass your fully qualified `sqlite` file's path to your `.env` file, like following:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE="/var/www/html/my-awesome-project/database/database.sqlite"
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Here change the value of `DB_DATABASE` key to the exact location of your `sqlite` file in your computer's filesystem.

**Tips:**
You can find your database's path for `sqlite` file by adding

```
dd(database_path('database.sqlite'));
```

this line of code in the top of `config/database.php` file and run `php artisan migrate` to terminal. You can find the exact location from there, copy it and put it to `.env`s `DB_DATABASE` key.

Don't forget to restart laravel server and remove `dd(database_path('database.sqlite'));` form `database.php` before testing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing `url: '%env(DATABASE_AUTH_URL)%'` to `url: '%env(resolve:AUTH_DATABASE_URL)%'` fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

At al most , You have to set the right path to your SQLite database file.

To mitigate the conflict between settings in .env file and database.php file in config folder, Just set database file path in database.php file and remove it from .env file.
.env file just write your connection and remove other database attributes.

> DB_CONNECTION=sqlite

second open config/database.php go to connections array and change database path to your database file path  **database_path('your database file path')**

```
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'database' => database_path('mydb.sqlite'),
        'prefix' => '',
        'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', false),
    ],
```

Answer (score -2):

Please check the permissions of the directory that database file is stored in. `chmod 777 YOU_APP/database`

Answer (score -3):

Change `DB_CONNECTION` from "mysql" to "sqlite".
Because this is an sqlite database, you can delete all the other `DB_*` items in that `.env` file.

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
```