# Invalid index even when value is selected

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I'm writing a PHP/HTML page that accesses a local SQLite database and displays/alters information from that database. I was having trouble connecting to the database, so I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668156/how-to-prevent-sqlite-sqlstatehy000-14) and now it SEEMS to be connecting. Now the issue I'm having is that when I run the code, select an option from the dropdown menu, and click submit, I get the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: formFlowerNameQuery in C:\Users\Aubrey\PhpstormProjects\Assignment5\src\main.php on line 45

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\Users\Aubrey\PhpstormProjects\Assignment5\src\main.php on line 46
```

I have no idea why the first error is occurring, as I have selected an option prior to hitting the submit button. The second one is confusing me as well, because the database shouldn't be null. Here's the HTML and PHP I'm running. This is also my first experience with both languages, so it may be a little hacked together from things I've found from googling what I want to do. The error is in respect to the first section named "Latest Sightings."

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Assignment 5</title>
</head>
<?php
global $database;
    function openDatabase(){
        try{
            if($this->database==null){
                $this->database =new PDO("sqlite:flowers.db","","",array(
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
                ));
            }
            return $this->database;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            print "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>SSWC Database</h1>
</header>
<hr noshade width=75%  align=left>
<h3>Latest Sightings</h3>
<p>To view the last 10 sightings of a flower, select it from the dropdown menu below and click submit.<p>
<p>
    <select name="formFlowerNameQuery">
        <option value="">Select Flower...</option>
        <option value="Draperia">Draperia</option>
        <option value="California flannelbush">California Flannelbush</option>
        <option value="Sheltons violet">Sheltons violet</option>
    </select>
</p>
<form action="main.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submitQuery" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitQuery'])){
        querySubmission($database);
    }

    function querySubmission($database){
        $varFlowerName = $_POST['formFlowerNameQuery'];
        $result = $database->query("SELECT PERSON, LOCATION, SIGHTED
                                    FROM SIGHTINGS
                                    WHERE NAME = $varFlowerName
                                    ORDER BY SIGHTED DESC
                                    LIMIT 10");
        while($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
            echo "NAME: " . $row['NAME'] . "\n";
            echo "PERSON: " . $row['PERSON'] . "\n";
            echo "LOCATION: " . $row['LOCATION'] . "\n";
            echo "SIGHTED ON: " . $row['SIGHTED'] . "\n";
        }
    }
?>
<hr noshade width=75%  align=left>
<h3>Update Flower Information</h3>
<p>To update information on a specific flower, select the flower from the dropdown menu <br />
    and input the new information into the provided text boxes. Click submit to update.</p>
<p>
    <select name="formFlowerNameUpdate">
        <option value="">Select Flower...</option>
        <option value="Draperia">Draperia</option>
        <option value="California flannelbush">California Flannelbush</option>
        <option value="Sheltons violet">Sheltons violet</option>
    </select>
</p>
<form>
    Genus:<br>
    <input type="text" name="genus"><br>
    Species:<br>
    <input type="text" name="species"><br>
    Common Name<br>
    <input type="text" name="comname"><br>
    <br />
</form>
<button name="submitUpdate">Submit</button>

<hr noshade width=75%  align=left>
<h3>Add Sighting</h3>
<p>To add a new flower sighting to the database, select the flower from the drop down menu <br />
    and input the sighting information. Click submit to add the sighting to the database.</p>
<p>
    <select name="formFlowerNameInsert">
        <option value="">Select Flower...</option>
        <option value="Draperia">Draperia</option>
        <option value="California flannelbush">California Flannelbush</option>
        <option value="Sheltons violet">Sheltons violet</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p>
    <select name="formPerson">
        <option value="">Select Person...</option>
        <option value="Jennifer">Jennifer</option>
        <option value="Maria">Maria</option>
        <option value="Michael">Michael</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p>
    <select name="formLocation">
        <option value="">Select Location...</option>
        <option value="Scodie Mountains">Scodie Mountains</option>
        <option value="Grouse Meadow">Grouse Meadow</option>
        <option value="Steve Spring">Steve Spring</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="date" name="dateSighted">
</p>
<button name="submitInsert">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Both errors have been fixed by following steps in @Phil's and @IncredibleHat's comments below.

Comment: @IncredibleHat, thanks! That fixed the index notice. I'm not following you on the fatal error though. I have $database defined as global in the first block of PHP code, so shouldn't it's scope span the whole file? Or does it only span within that block of PHP?

Comment: Why are you using `$this` without a class? Also, don't use `global` anywhere, ever. Just use `$database = openDatabase();`

Comment: I meant: The `$database` inside the other functions is undefined, so to speak, because you have only created `$database` inside the function `openDatabase`. And I don't see `openDatabase();` being called, and its using `$this` as @Phil said, which would break too if you ever did call that standalone function as its written.

Comment: @Phil, I got that code from the post I linked above. I was getting a database connection error and searched on stackoverflow to find a solution and that was the one given. I'll edit it and see if I can get it working.

Comment: @a.sapp you obviously missed some vital components when copying that code

Comment: @Phil, I removed the references to global and $this as well as the if statement in the try/catch block. It's working now, however it's now returning an error saying that the fetchArray() method is being used on a boolean. What would be the proper way to retrieve the query result?

Comment: That means your query is returning an error. Add `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` to the array you're passing in to `new PDO`. My guess is it's due to the unquoted string value `$varFlowerName`. Use a prepared statement with bound parameters instead

Answer (score -1):

that is because you put tne `select` field outside your `form`

```
<p>
    <select name="formFlowerNameQuery">
        <option value="">Select Flower...</option>
        <option value="Draperia">Draperia</option>
        <option value="California flannelbush">California Flannelbush</option>
        <option value="Sheltons violet">Sheltons violet</option>
    </select>
</p>
<form action="main.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submitQuery" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

change it to

```
<form action="main.php" method="post">
<p>
    <select name="formFlowerNameQuery">
        <option value="">Select Flower...</option>
        <option value="Draperia">Draperia</option>
        <option value="California flannelbush">California Flannelbush</option>
        <option value="Sheltons violet">Sheltons violet</option>
    </select>
</p>
    <input type="submit" name="submitQuery" value="Submit" />
</form>
```